# Far Cry 3 Service Is Unavailable?

Tags: far-cry-3

I just bought Far Cry 3 on Steam and I have been trying to connect online to UBI. However it times out and gives this message.

[image]

This means I cannot go and play Multiplayer or Coop and whenever I play single player and go to the pause screen I get this annoying 30 second time interval with it trying to connect to the service.

How do I fix this problem?

I am using a router and firewall but I made sure nothing is being blocked.

Comment: UPlay [might just be down again](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77764/driver-san-francisco-pauses-for-about-10-seconds-every-30-seconds/77765#77765) :( this happened during the summer sales, as well.

Comment: Welcome to Ubisoft's "we've fixed it, really!" DRM.

Comment: 'Always Online' DRM is the absolute worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't the only one. Ubisoft got some problems with keeping the online servers up and running.

You can see their [twitter account](http://twitter.com/FarCrygame) for news about the situation. As you can see it's full of "it's working - it's not working - it's working again - oops, it's off again" messages.

Comment: DRM for the win

Comment: Not DRM per se, as you CAN play the game offline. Extremely annoying, though.